# Java Locale and DecimalFormat does not format poland currency as expected

Tags: java, locale, currency-formatting

I am facing a problem with currency formatting. I have locale setting such that i create locale, passing language code pl and country code PL, i can not change it. Now currency is formatted by a comma ',' in Poland. So 10.00 becomes 10,00. Now when I format polish currency using Locale("pl","PL"), it formats currency as 10 zł. But if I use format locale as  Locale("pl"), it gives ¤ 10,00. , a comma separated currency which i want. But i have to use Locale("pl","PL"), i can not change it. But this locale is not formatting currency as it should. Is it an issue with DecimalFormat class, any idea?

,,,

```
    Number number = new BigDecimal("10.00");        
    Locale locale1 = new Locale("pl");
    DecimalFormat cf1 = (DecimalFormat) 
    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale1);
    String pl = cf1.format (number);
    System.out.println(pl); // it prints this: ¤ 10,00


    Locale locale2 = new Locale("pl","PL");     
    DecimalFormat cf2 = (DecimalFormat) 
    NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale2);
    String pl_PL = cf2.format (number); 
    System.out.println(pl_PL); //it prints this: 10 zł
```

,,,

Comment: So you just want two decimal places?

Comment: I want that if i pass polish locale as Locale("pl","PL"), i should get comma formatted currency : 10,00

Comment: Well, if you pass in a non-integer the comma will appear. Are you qualified (i.e. Polish) to say that `10 zł` is _not_ how Polish people format their currencies? If not, then what you really want is two decimal places, which can be easily achieved by `cf2.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);`.

Comment: Yes I am. Polish currency formats separated with a comma. Problem i want to state is, what changes if i change locale from Locale("pl") to Locale("pl","PL")? Why currency formatting starts behaving differently.?

Comment: `Locale("pl","PL")` specifies both the _language_ and _country_, whereas `Locale("pl")` only specifies the _language_. As far as Java is concerned, numbers in the _Polish Language_ are formatted with `,` as the decimal separator, and currencies in _Poland_ the country are formatted with as  few fractional digits as possible. Whether that is true in real life, I don't know.